# Como se proteger de uma entrada maliciosa através de um select dropdown?

Tags: php, sql-injection

Possuo um `form` com algumas opções de `select`, exemplo :

```
<select id="sel1" name="sel1">
    <option disabled selected style="display: none">Titulo</option>
    <option value="op1">op1</option>
    <option value="op2">op2</option>
    <option value="op3">op3</option>
</select>
```

Minha dúvida é, se tratar essa entrada com `mysqli_real_escape_string` é suficiente, exemplo :

```
$sel1 =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sel1']);
```

Ou preciso de mais algum cuidado, se sim quais seriam os pontos que deveria ter atenção ?

Answer (score 1):

Uma das possíveis formas de validar seria utilizando a função `in_array` do PHP para fazer essa verificação.

```
if (! in_array($_POST['valor'], ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3']) {
   // inválido
}
```

Pois alguém poderia editar, via ferramenta do desenvolvedor, o valor do seu `select`, essa pessoa conseguiria facilmente inserir um valor desconhecido lá na sua tabela do banco de dados.

Veja:

<kbd>[image: Segurança num Select]</kbd>

Nesse exemplo acima, eu poderia simplesmente alterar o valor no front-end e enviar uma submissão.

Além do mais, existem ferramentas que permitem envio de formulário, independente da sua definição, como por exemplo o plugin Postman, do *Google Chrome*. Com ele é possível enviar requisições para determinada URL,  podendo ser passado o valor que você quiser.
Sendo assim, conhecendo a URL, posso enviar o que eu quiser pro seu servidor.

É por isso que recomendo fortemente que a validação seja sempre feita no servidor, uma vez que sua estrutura para envio dos dados pelo lado cliente (falo da programação do HTML e JavaScript) não garante a veracidade dos mesmos.

É importante definir o que você quer receber no servidor.

Um erro muito comum que vejo é a pessoa que usa a variável $_GET para pegar o valor da página que será incluída.

Exemplo:

```
 $page = $_GET['page'];
 Include 'paginas/' . $page . '.php';
```

No exemplo acima obviamente se espera uma string. Mas pra saber o nível de conhecimento do programador basta passar um `page[]=1` como parâmetro. Não será surpresa se aparecer um "array conversion to string", pois não era esperado isso.

Em tais casos por falta de verificação aparecem erros mais feios, por conta de falta de validação.

Nesse caso um simples `filter_var` ou `filter_input` resolveria o problema.

```
$page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page');

if ($page === false) exit;

include 'paginas/' . $page . '.php';
```

Só `mysql_escape_string` não garante nada. Eu sugiro formatar e validar  os dados sempre da maneira que você quer receber.

Em resumo: Você não deve jamais confiar apenas na validação feita do lado do cliente (o navegador), tendo em vista que tudo pode ser manipulado.

Comment: " aí você teria uma opção desconhecida lá na sua tabela do banco de dados" , que poderia ser um comando injection ?

Comment: @MagicHat eu vou postar um exemplo mais completo no meu almoço. É uma hora mais tranquila :p. Mas adiantando: se o cara editar o "value" do seu "option" ele pode mandar até um `array` para seu backend se ele quiser.

Comment: Sem pressa, amigo... tks

Comment: @MagicHat se o cara fizer `name="sel[][][]"`, você poderá receber um `array` num lugar inexperado. Vou elaborar uma resposta que ensine a usar `filter_var` ou `filter_input`.

Comment: Sem esse filtro um maluco poderia enviar um "opXXXXX" no valor do "sel1", tipo: "sel1=QueQueÉOP", dai você ia cadastrar no banco como "QueQueÉOP", sendo que não era uma opção válida (os "validos" seriam apenas o op1, op2 e op3).

Comment: @Inkeliz exato.  Já ouviu falar de "PostMan"? Você pode colocar qualquer coisa no formulário e fazer um submit :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters se possível, também aborde a primeira opção da lista do dropdown, que não possui um `name`, tenho que tomar algum cuidado com ela tmb ?

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que a regra básica para qualquer informação enviada pelo usuário é de *"nunca confiar na informação enviada pelo cliente"*

Devo dizer que não trabalho com PHP, mas isso vale para qualquer linguagem, enquanto o uso do `mysqli_real_escape_string` ou equivalentes em outras linguagens te dá a segurança (se usado corretamente) de que não vai ter problema de SQL Injection ela não te garante que as informações que o usuário enviou estão corretas.

Você deve sempre validar todas as informações que o usuário envia, no caso de um Dropdown você deve ter certeza que o usuário poderia ter escolhido o valor que foi enviado, e geralmente você deve fazer duas validações, uma por javascript, ela realmente não é necessária mas ajuda a evitar posts incorretos de usuários legítimos, e a outra, esta obrigatória, é a no servidor, pois só ali você pode ter certeza que os dados estão corretos.